# Read a multipage tiff?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

I'm trying to sort out how to open a multi-page tiff. The sender swears it has more than one page, but in the default viewer I'm only able to see the first page. How do I view all pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Evince is supposed to open multipage tiffs. If not, another application to try is imview found in the Software Center.

Comment: I don't have a multipage tiff to try this out. If you would supply it, I could find an application that works.

Answer (score 2):

The `display` utility from the ImageMagick-6 suite of tools can be used to view a multi-page tiff file.  I use the following command to view the tiff files scanned using a HP 8270 multi-function printer:

```
display -rotate 90 -resize 1920x1080 Musings.tif
```

The `display` utility has **many** command line options, of which I found the above necessary.  `-resize`, which is a bit finicky as to what resolution it accepts, permits viewing the entire image at a reduced resolution without scrolling.

To turn pages, right-click anywhere on the image, then without releasing the button, move the cursor down to `Next` or `Former` on the context-menu, then release the button.  I have not yet found a menu that directly moves to any page/image within the file; however, there may be a command-line option for selecting which images to view. (The `display` man page is rather cryptic due to its brevity.)

Also, the `tiff-tools` package has a number of utilities, of which the following are particularly useful:

- `tiffcp` : copy or concatenate images from one tiff file to another, optionally selecting and resequencing images from the input file(s).
- `tiffinfo` : display the metadata for every image in a tiff.
- `tiffsplit` : split a tiff file into individual files, each containing a single image.

Here is an example of using `tiffcp` to create a new tiff file containing selected images from one file and all images from another:

```
tiffcp Musings-1.tif,5,6,0,1,2,3,4  Musings-2.tif Musings_new.tif
```

The `tiff-tools` package also has a number of other utilities for editing and converting images in tiff files.

Comment: I have subsequently discovered that the `Evince` (`Atril` on Ubuntu MATE) `document viewer` is a much better option than `display`.

Comment: The package is now named `libtiff-tools`, at least for Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

**evince** did not work for me.
I found that the program **okular** works for multipage tiff's.

Comment: what wents wrong with evince? I used it, and it works with multiple tiff.

Comment: "Unable to open document "file:....".  File type TIFF image (image/tiff) is not supported

Comment: which version of evince what not working? I used 3.36.0 and it works fine with multiple page tiff. (on ubuntu 20.04)